# How to get a single value of a collection in MongoDB python

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I have the following python code in MongoDB:

```py
input_1 = object_collection.find({"_id": ObjectId(key_1)})
   for i in input_1:
       print(i)
```

and it returns this:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5d949843cc1e1fc0556983bc'), 'x_input': '11', 'y_input': '22'}
```

I am interested only in `x_input` and `y_input` where I would like to store them in order to calculate the same of them

Answer (score 0):

So you can use 'project' in your query...

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import ObjectId

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = MongoClient("localhost:27017", username="barry", password="barry", authSource="admin", authMechanism="SCRAM-SHA-256")

    with client.start_session(causal_consistency = True) as my_session:
        with my_session.start_transaction():

            db = client.mydatabase
            collection = db.mycollection

            for result in collection.find({"_id": ObjectId("5d97713e11261b4afebe517b")}, {"_id": 0, "x_input": 1}):                          
                print (str(result))
```

See the bit ...

```
{"_id": 0, "x_input": 1}
```

... this instructs the query engine to turn off display for "_id", and turn on display for "x_input".  If we specific any 'project' at all, then all fields we want to see must be specified.  "_id" is the oddball to this strategy and will always show unless turned off.

Results:

```
{u'x_input': u'11'}
```